# How to make an old C codebase with many globals reentrant

Tags: c++, c, refactoring, automated-refactoring, reentrancy

I'm working with a large, old C codebase (an interpreter) that uses global variables a great deal, with the result that I cannot have two instances of it at once.  Is there a straightforward (ideally automated) approach to convert this code to something reentrant? i.e. some refactor tool that would make all globals part of a struct and prepend the pointer to all variables?

Could I convert to C++ and wrap the entire thing in a class definition?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "instances"? You should be able to run the program twice without problems. If you mean instances of some struct that represents your interpreter, that's a different story. Second, how large is "large" and how much time do you have for this?

Comment: @arne "large" = 50k sloc, certainly not time I have something to do by hand. By "instances" I mean two separate interpreters running different code.  I would like to be able to do this in separate threads, hence the need for something truly reentrant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to convert your project into C++11 project and change all your static vars into `threadlocal`.

This can be up to several days of work depending on the size of your project. In certain cases this will work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any "ready made" solution for this type of problem.

As a general rule, global variables are going to make it hard to make the code reentrant.

If you can remove all the global variables [simply delete the globals and see where you get compiler errors]. Replace the globals with a structure, and then use a structure per instance that is passed along, you'd be pretty much done (as long as the state of the interpreter instances is independent, and the instances don't need to know about each other). [Of course, you may need to have more than a single structure to solve the problem, but your global variables should be possible to "stick in a structure"].

Of course, making the structure and the code go together as a C++ class (which may have smaller classes as part of the solution) would be the "next step", but it's not entirely straight forward to do this, if you are not familiar with C++ and class designs.

Comment: Yup - shove all the globals in a C++ class as instance vars.  Why would it not be straghtforward?  Should work, no?

Comment: @MartinJames Code that takes addresses of functions and passes them on to C code will certainly break.

Comment: @user4815162342 - with member functions, sure it will.  I kinda assumed that the OP would not do that:)

Comment: @MartinJames I understand the OP's idea is to wrap virtually the entire code base into `class foo { ... }`, so that global variables become class members and C functions become class member functions. This would magically transform all globals into members with minimal changes to the legacy code base. While a neat idea, I think it will break, first because getting a huge C code base to compile with C++ is harder than it seems, and second because of traps presented by pointers to functions and possibly other advanced C features.

Comment: @user4815162342 - OK, fair points. I also do C/C++ interop, so I appreciate that there can be 'issues', eg. C calls that setup callbacks but have no aux 'void*' parameter:((

Comment: @MartinJames Exactly... my answer outlines a different strategy that requires a bit more work upfront, but is IMHO more workable in the long run. It also doesn't require conversion to C++.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make it reentrant in order to be able to make it multi-thread, and divide the work between threads? 
If so, I would consider making it multi process, instead of multy-thread,

Comment: That makes it difficult to communicate between interpreter instances.

Comment: @yosim Also, this may end up on iOS or Android one day, so multi process is not an option.

Comment: @Martin, for the communication between interpreter processes, you can look at the following lib: [link] https://github.com/gby/coproc

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do with interpreters is go straight to a class with instance vars rather than globals.  Not sure what you are interpreting, but it could be possible to pass in a file path or string container that the class interprets with an internal thread, so encapsulating the entire interpretation run.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to wrap the whole thing in a class definition, but it will not work for code that takes addresses of functions and passes them to C code. Also, converting a large legacy code base to be compilable by a C++ compiler is tedious enough that it probably outweighs the effort of removing the global variables by hand.

Barring that one, you have two options:

1. Since you need reentrancy to implement threading, it might be easiest to declare all global variables *thread-local*. If you have a C compiler that [supports thread-locals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gcc/Thread_002dLocal.html#Thread_002dLocal), this is typically as easy as slapping a `__thread` (or other compiler-specific keyword) before every declaration. Then you create a new interpreter simply by creating a new thread and initializing the interpreter in the normal way.
2. If you cannot use `__thread` or equivalent, then you have to do a bit more footwork. You need to place all global variables in a structure, and replace every access to global variable `foo` with `get_ctx()->foo`. This is tedious, but straightforward. Once you are done, `get_ctx()` can allocate and return a thread-local interpreter state, using an [API of your choosing](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/pthread_key_create.html).

Answer (score 0):

A program transformation tool that can handle the C language would be able to automate such changes. 
It needs to be able to resolve each symbol to its declaration, and preprocessor conditionals are likely to be trouble.   I'd name one, but SO zealots object when I do that.

Your solution of a struct containing the globals is the right idea; you need rewrite that replaces each global declaration with a slot member, and each access to a global with access to the corresponding struct member.

The remaining question is, where does the struct pointer come from?  One answer is a global variable that is multiplexed when threads are switched; a better answer if available under your OS is the get the struct pointer from thread local variables.